# How can I limit the output of the whois command?

Tags: whois, parsing

How do I get only the owner/orgname from a PTR whois lookup?
I don't need all the other entires, just the part about ownership (google in this case).

`Edit`    /usr/bin/whois  74.125.236.52 or any ip
          `get OrgName`

```
  #
  # Query terms are ambiguous.  The query is assumed to be:
  #     "n 74.125.236.52"
  #
  # Use "?" to get help.
  #

  #
  # The following results may also be obtained via:
  # http://whois.arin.net/rest/nets;q=74.125.236.52?showDetails=true&showARIN=false&ext=netref2
  #

  NetRange:       74.125.0.0 - 74.125.255.255
  CIDR:           74.125.0.0/16
  OriginAS:
  NetName:        GOOGLE
  NetHandle:      NET-74-125-0-0-1
  Parent:         NET-74-0-0-0-0
  NetType:        Direct Allocation
  RegDate:        2007-03-13
  Updated:        2012-02-24
  Ref:            http://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-74-125-0-0-1


  OrgName:        Google Inc.
  OrgId:          GOGL
  Address:        1600 Amphitheatre Parkway
  City:           Mountain View
  StateProv:      CA
  PostalCode:     94043
  Country:        US
  RegDate:        2000-03-30
  Updated:        2011-09-24
  Ref:            http://whois.arin.net/rest/org/GOGL

  OrgAbuseHandle: ZG39-ARIN
  OrgAbuseName:   Google Inc
  OrgAbusePhone:  +1-650-253-0000
  OrgAbuseEmail:  arin-contact@google.com
  OrgAbuseRef:    http://whois.arin.net/rest/poc/ZG39-ARIN

  OrgTechHandle: ZG39-ARIN
  OrgTechName:   Google Inc
  OrgTechPhone:  +1-650-253-0000
  OrgTechEmail:  arin-contact@google.com
  OrgTechRef:    http://whois.arin.net/rest/poc/ZG39-ARIN

  #
  # ARIN WHOIS data and services are subject to the Terms of Use
  # available at: https://www.arin.net/whois_tou.html
  #
```

Comment: Well, that edit changed the thrust of the question somewhat. @Rajeev, is it the *domain name* or the *organisation name* that you're really after?

Answer (score 6):

If you want the *domain name* of the owner of an IP-address (rather than, say, a *company name*), perhaps you might be better served by using `dig -x` ?

```
$ dig +short -x 74.125.236.52
maa03s04-in-f20.1e100.net.
```

-- EDIT --

If you just want the "OrgName:" line from the `whois` output, you can single it out with `grep`:

```
$ whois 74.125.236.52 | grep OrgName
OrgName:        Google Inc.
```

As mentioned elsewhere though, this may not always work, since the output-format is not specified anywhere.

Comment: how to get google domain name using above

Comment: The domain `1e100.net` is owned by Google - not all of Google's services live on a "google.com" domain. Specifically, it's the domain that all Google servers live on, as per http://support.google.com/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=174717

Comment: but what if i want to query other servers info

Comment: Feel free to edit the question to list *exactly* what you're after.

Comment: i have edited the question

Answer (score 3):

The `whois` output is not standardized, so there isn't any toggle to only get the information you're looking for.

What you need is some parsing (`grep`/`sed`/ `awk` and so on), and this site is not suited for that. Ask on Stack Overflow instead.

Answer (score 2):

man whois return how to can format data for get only that you like

Example

```
whois -H -K 37.247.93.241

% This is the RIPE Database query service.
% The objects are in RPSL format.
%
% The RIPE Database is subject to Terms and Conditions.
% See http://www.ripe.net/db/support/db-terms-conditions.pdf

% Note: this output has been filtered.
% Only primary keys and abuse contacts will be visible.
% No other contact information will be shown.

% Abuse contact for '37.247.93.0 - 37.247.93.255' is 'abuse@envia-tel.net'

inetnum:        37.247.93.0 - 37.247.93.255

route:          37.247.64.0/19
origin:         AS21413

% This query was served by the RIPE Database Query Service version 1.97.2 (HEREFORD)
```